# Add an object with array to database FireBase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to save an object in my firebase database, which contains an array.

when i use this:

```
mDatabaseReference.child("user").child(id).setValue(user);
```

i dont see the array in my database.

#####edited#####

this is my class UserInformation:

```
public class UserInformation {


private String email1;
private String Password1;
public HashMap<String, Boolean> levels=new HashMap<>();

public UserInformation (String email, String Password){
    this.email1=email;
    this.Password1=Password;
    levels.put("level1", false);
    levels.put("level2", false);
    levels.put("level3", false);

}
```

and its still not working, i dont see my hash in the root of  mt data base:
when I use

```
 UserInformation user=new UserInformation(email1,password1);
                String id=mDatabaseReference.push().getKey();
                mDatabaseReference.child("user").child(id).setValue(user);
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ProfileActivity.class));
```

what can i do?

Comment: post your firebase tree structure, a screenshot will be fine

Comment: What **do** you see? Is the rest of the object added?

Comment: @cricket_007 yes

Comment: Can you add your user class to the question please? As well as the code to create that object?

Comment: Please see my updated answer, which provides 2 different methods of addig data in a Firebase database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Official documentation of Firebase recommends against using `arrays`. Trying to use an array, is an anti-pattern when it comes to Firebase. Beside that, one of the many reasons Firebase recommends against using arrays is that it makes the security rules impossible to write. Because a Firebase database is structured as pairs of key and values, the best option is to use a `Map`.

Below an example of setting a value on two different references.

```
Map<String, Object> childUpdates = new HashMap<>();
childUpdates.put("/posts/" + key, postValues);
childUpdates.put("/user-posts/" + userId + "/" + key, postValues);
mDatabaseReference.setValue(childUpdates);
```

or using objects:

```
UserInformation ui = new UserInformation(email, Password);
mDatabaseReference.setValue(ui);
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

To save your object into the Database.

```
public class UserInformation {


private String email1;
private String Password1;
public HashMap<String, Boolean> levels=new HashMap<>();

public UserInformation (String email, String Password){
    this.email1=email;
    this.Password1=Password;
    levels.put("level1", false);
    levels.put("level2", false);
    levels.put("level3", false);

}
```

Now create the object of your UserInformation class.

```
     UserInformation user=new UserInformation(email1,password1);
DatabaseReference userReference = mDatabaseReference.child("user");
                    String id=userReference.push().getKey();
                    userReference.child(id).setValue(user);
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ProfileActivity.class));
```

If this doesn't work out then add the event listener and check if data is being saved on your `FirebaseDatabase` and **be sure that you have changed the firebase database rules to read and write**

Thanks